# Setup password for ubuntu bootloader to protect my system from clearing root password?

Tags: grub2

How to set a password for the grub so it prompt for user authentication to boot the system .

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by adding a password line in Grub.  To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Add the following `password` line to the grub configuration file.

```
default=0
timeout=15
password HhdahyG@SVAGh%
```

You can use any password of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

**Backup** `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` **to another location.** Then,

1. Edit the `/etc/grub.d/00_header*`, `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, and `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` files, open them as root with a text editor (like `gedit`):

   `$ gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/00_header /etc/grub.d/10_linux /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`
2. A superuser must be designated. This user can select all menuentries, edit any items in the `GRUB 2` menu during the boot process, and access the `GRUB 2` terminal.

   Open `/etc/grub.d/00_header` and add the following at the bottom of the file:

   `cat << EOF
   set superusers="ezio"
   password ezio foo
   password zo bar 
   EOF`

   See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords#Password_Encryption) for encrypting your password i.e. `foo` here.
3. The `GRUB 2` menu can contain protected and unprotected items.

   `All Users (No menuentry protection): menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu -class os --unrestricted{
   Superuser Only: menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu -class os --users "" {
   Superuser + ezio: menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic' --class ubuntu -class os --users ezio {`
4. In `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, find the following line:

   `printf "menuentry '${title}' ${CLASS} {\n" "${os}" "${version}"`

   Add `--users '' :`

   `printf "menuentry '${title}' ${CLASS} --users '' {\n" "${os}" "${version}"`
5. Update `GRUB 2` with the new changes:

   `$ sudo update-grub`